# Libertinus pdflatex vs. lualatex: Delmiting vertical bars (left, right, middle) do not scale correctly and are too thin

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, delimiters

Compile this MWE with PdfLaTeX and with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert
  P \left[
    b = b'
  \middle\vert
    \begin{gathered}
      g \gets G\\
      2 = 1 + 1
    \end{gathered}
  \right] \right\rvert
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The result with PdfLaTeX is this:

[image: Resut with PdfLaTeX]

The vertical bars are nearly as thick and high as the squared brackets. Not completely, but the difference is not so much that it would be visually disturbing.

The result with LuaLaTeX is this:

[image: Result with LuaLaTeX]

The vertical bars are too small, but most disturbing is the difference between the thickness of the squared brackets and the thickness of the vertical bars.

Overall, I like the result with LuaLaTex better (mostly because the lowercase g matches the g in text mode), but I would either have thinner squared bracket such that they match the thickness of the vertical bars or vice versa.

How do achieve this? Are `\lvert`, `\rvert` and `\vert` the "correct" commands to be used with unicode-math or are are there successors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't like the symbols provided by `Libertinus Math`, you can load them from another math font you like.

You can select the symbols you want to change with option `range=`.

Let's try `Fira Math`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\setmathfont[range={\vert,\lbrack,\rbrack}]{FiraMath-Regular.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert
  P \left[
    b = b'
  \middle\vert
    \begin{gathered}
      g \gets G\\
      2 = 1 + 1
    \end{gathered}
  \right] \right\rvert
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe `Latin Modern Math` fits better:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\setmathfont[range={\vert,\lbrack,\rbrack}]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\lvert
  P \left[
    b = b'
  \middle\vert
    \begin{gathered}
      g \gets G\\
      2 = 1 + 1
    \end{gathered}
  \right] \right\rvert
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your code. But every command is it too thick that looks like a bold character?

Comment: I voted for it :); but if you find something where \lvert and \rvert is less thick aesthetically it might be better.

Comment: @Sebastiano got it

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know you could use a font selectively like this. TIL.